# No user names visible at Pantheon Greeter until click

Tags: release-loki, greeter

I recently installed elementary OS Loki.

At the login screen I have 3 users (2 created users and a guest) represented by blue icons. I don't see the login names behind the blue icons until I click in the space behind the icon. (I have to click icon by icon in order to find the correct user to login.) This also happens in a virtual machine, but screenshots on the Internet suggest that I should see the names behind all icons in the greeter screen. Am I doing something wrong?